# Drupal 6x Wall-like module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a FB Wall-like module for Drupal 6x?

I'm looking for module which will list all comments, privatemessages and other actions done around user account in a short table.

I would like to avoid using views (heavy!).

Some useful thoughts:
http://groups.drupal.org/node/17847

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use Views as often os possible. It's one of the top modules for a reason. FOr you wall, you should combinate it with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

If you realy want a avoid views, you should create different page regions that hold different parts of the wall inside them (but again, Panels already are capeable of creating something like this).